# Increase date value of current time in php using yii framework

Tags: php, date, yii

I am new in coding with php and using yii framework.

Can any one help me with my problem.I have to date field in my database,One is upload date another is review date.I have taken the current date as upload date. here is the code:

```
$model = new CvUpload;
$model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];
$model->upload_date = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
```

Now i need to do is add 90days to the upload date and save the increase value to review date field..Can any one help me with code example.AS im very poor at coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using `date()` instead of `NOW()`:

```
 $model=new CvUpload;
 $model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];
 $model->upload_date = new CDbExpression("(date('D')+ 90)");

or this:

CDbExpression('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAYS)');

or this:

date('Y-m-d', strtotime(NOW() ' + 90 days'));
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick responce @Crazzy Skull....I tried the date('Y-m-d', strtotime(NOW() ' + 90 days')); and it working fine.... again thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mysql expression `$model->review_date = new CDbExpression('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAYS)');`

Comment: I tried you suggestion but the days were not adding in my review_date field....dont know why...but when i tried this => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(NOW() ' + 90 days')); it was working, may be i was not doing the right way.....anyway thanks for your response.. @chris